# Python: least square fit with side conditions on fit-parameters

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a timeseries that I want to fit to function using Scipy.optimize.leastsq.

```
fitfunc= lambda a, x:     a[0]+a[1]*exp(-x/a[4])+a[2]*exp(-x/a[5])+a[3]*exp(-x    /a[6])    
errfunc lambda a,x,y:     fitfunc(a,x) - y
```

Next I would pass errfunc to leastsq to minimze it. The fit-function I use is a sum of exponentials decaying with different timescales a(4:6) and different weights (a(0:4)). (as a sideuqestion: can I use leastsq with more than 1 parameter arrays? I didn't suceed to do so....)

The question: How can I put additional side conditions on the parameters entering the fit-function. I want for example that sum(a(0:4))=1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
import numpy as np

def fitfunc(p, x):
    a = np.zeros(7)
    a[1:7] = p[:6]
    a[0] = 1 - a[1:4].sum()
    return a[0] + a[1]*exp(-x/a[4]) + a[2]*exp(-x/a[5]) + a[3]*exp(-x/a[6])

def errfunc(p, x, y1, y2):
    return np.concatenate((
        fitfunc(p[:6], x) - y1,
        fitfunc(p[6:12], x) - y2
    ))
```

Generally, lambda-functions are considered bad style (and they don't add anything in your code). To have several functions in the least square fit you may just append the functions as I indicated using np.concatenate. It doesn't make much sense, if none of the parameters are correlated, though. It will only slow down convergence of the algorithm. The side condition you asked for, is implemented by just calculating one weight based on the constraint you gave (see 1 - a[1:4].sum()).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve the equations for you constraints, and you can live with the constraint being satisfied with some tolerance, another possibility is to add a term to the chi-square with the large weight which guarantees that the constraint is almost satisfied.

E.g if you need that \sum(sin(p[i])==1 ,you can do the following:

```
constraint_func = lambda a: sin(a).sum()-1

def fitfunc (a,x):
    np.concatenate((a[0]+a[1]*exp(-x/a[4])+a[2]*exp(-x/a[5])+a[3]*exp(-x /a[6]),
                   [constraint_func(a)]))

def errfunc(a,x,y):
    tolerance = 1e-10
    return np.concatenate((fitfunc(a,x) - y, [tolerance]))
```

Obviously the convergence will be slower, but will be still guaranteed.